# How do you sort the output of a python command?

Tags: python, sorting

Python beginner here. Let's say that I have something at the end of my script that queries info from a system and dumps it into this format:

```
print my_list_of_food(blah)
```

and it outputs a list like:

```
('Apples', 4, 4792320)
('Oranges', 2, 2777088)
('Pickles', 3, 4485120)
('Pumpkins', 1, 5074944)
('more stuff', 4545, 345345)
```

How do I then sort that output based on the 2nd field so that it would look like this:

```
('Pumpkins', 1, 5074944)
('Oranges', 2, 2777088)
('Pickles', 3, 4485120)
('Apples', 4, 4792320)
```

Other than importing a bash command to `cut -d "," -f 2 | head 4` I'd rather use python. I know I can use sorted or sort to sort an existing tuple or dictionary but I'm not sure of how to sort the output of a print. I've done some research and everything points to implementing sort into my script instead of sorting a print output but who knows, maybe someone has a solution. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Thanks everyone. I've tried to make all of the solutions work but I keep getting this error:

```
File "test.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    print sorted(my_list_of_food(blah), key=lambda x: x[1])
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

File "test.py", line 18, in <lambda>
    print(sorted(my_list_of_food(blah), key=lambda k: k[1]))
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

I tried to include this at the beginning of the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the key argument to the sort. In your case,

```
print(sorted(list_of_food, key=lambda k:k[1]))
```

will do the trick. The key function should return an integer, usually.

Comment: "the key function should return an integer, usually" -- I don't think that's true at all ...

Comment: Actually yeah, you're right... What I meant was that it should return some value with a natural ordering -- any number, or a string, or other types could work. Sorry.

Comment: Also notice that he is using python2 on the question. Using `print` as a function may be confusing here

Comment: More importantly, I suspect `my_list_of_food` could be a function that returns a string.... If you printed a list or set object, it wouldn't print with newlines between the members.

Comment: @goncalopp: The print function works back to 2.6, so this is likely valid Python 2.

Comment: @Peter I didn't mean to say you *can't* use `print()` - it is, indeed, valid python2, as long as you have a recent 2.x or you import from `__future__`. It's just that @mister mister has mentioned that he's a begginer, so he may stumble on the possible `SyntaxError`

Comment: @goncalopp -- Also note that using parenthesis around a single object like this allows this line of code to be used in python2.x and python3.x ... I do this all the time :)

Comment: @mgilson I had an "aha" moment there - I had no idea the parser didn't need the whitespace after print (I thought Peter was talking about `__future__`). This is indeed very useful, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort after outputting to `stdout`. Well, you shouldn't, since it's heavily complicating a simple task. Instead, you sort **the value** and print the result:

```
print sorted(my_list_of_food(blah), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The part where you were having difficulties is sorting by the second field; that's why that `key` argument is there - to override the default ordering (which would be the first item of the tuple). To learn more about key functions, check [this section on the python Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

If you're still wondering, technically, you *could* sort the `stdout` output if you replaced `sys.stdout` with a wrapper object that buffered the output then sorted and printed it (to the real stdout) periodically, but it's pointless and hard to get right, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If it prints out that way, than either `my_list_of_food(blah)` returns a string, or it returns a class instance that has a `__repr__` method that returns that string... Your best bet is to get data in the actual list format before it becomes a string.

If it returns a class instance, get the list and sort on it using key... Otherwise you need to parse the text, so I'll address that part only:

```
# this is assuming the structure is consistent
# function to parse a line of the form "('{text}', {int}, {int})" into tuple members using regex
import re
re_line = re.compile(r"\('(?P<name>\w*)',\s?(?P<int1>\d+)\s?,\s?(?P<int2>\d+)\)")
def ParseLine(line):
    m = re_line.match(line)
    if m:
        return (m.group('name'), int(m.group('int1')), int(m.group('int2')))
    # otherwise return a tuple of None objects
    else:
        return (None, None, None)

# final sorted output (as tuples of (str, int, int) )
sorted( 
    [ParseLine(line) for line in my_list_of_food(blah).splitlines()],
    key = lambda tup: tup[1]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK: If you really have to do it that way: capture the output of the function in 
a StringIO object and sort the lines read back from that object.

```
import sys
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO

a = [ ('Apples', 4, 4792320), 
    ('Oranges', 2, 2777088), 
    ('Pickles', 3, 4485120), 
    ('Pumpkins', 1, 5074944), 
    ('more stuff', 4545, 345345) ]
```

## [Step 1]

```
out = StringIO()    # create a StringIO object
sys.stdout = out    # and redirect stdout to it
for item in a : print (item)        # print output
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__     # redirect stdout back to normal stdout

out.seek(0)     # rewind StringIO object
s = out.readlines() # and read the lines.
```

## [Step 2: define a key function to split the strings at comma,

## and compare the 2nd field numerically. ]

```
def sortkey(a):
   return int(a.split(',')[1].strip())
```

## [Step 3: sort and print]

```
s.sort(key=sortkey)
for line in s: print (line)
```